# how to work with kinect captured RGB-D without camera (Offline Stream sample code Please)?

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, depth, kinect-sdk

Is there any one who has any experience in programming with kinect without sensor? I mean that programing only by some sample RGB-D dataset without connected device, because I want to do my project with kinect and opencv but I dont want to buy the camera (it's costly for me).
If you know please let me know in any programming language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RGB-D dataset consists of .ONI recordings, the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) will provide easy I/O functions and many algorithms dedicated to 3D processing.

If you never used it, a good starting point is the [tutorial page](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/), which provides many code samples and explanations, and in particular [guides](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#basic-usage) to get started quickly.

For the specific concern of opening your .ONI sequences, you can follow [this tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber), which explains how to open a connected Kinect device to grab RGB-D data. However, if you replace the following instruction (on line 17) :

```
pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber();
```

by this one :

```
pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber(string_filename);
```

where `string_filename` is a `std::string` containing the path to an .ONI sequence, it will open it and treat it as a Kinect-stream being acquired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've already had my dataset and I need some sample codes for handling the captured stream with kinect SDK for example in c++

Comment: What is the format of your recorded data ?

Comment: .oni file format (by OpenNI package) and a zip file of individual color and depth images (both in .png format)

Comment: Actually I have no Idea about the format ant it's just the format of the files I received if you have any suggestion let me know to change it thank you

Comment: If you have .ONI recordings, the PCL is a good way to use them. See my edited answer.

Comment: could you tell me which one of OpenNi or Opencv is better in RGB-Depth programing? which one do you suggest?

Comment: Definitely not OpenCV. OpenNI is pretty low-level whereas the Point Cloud Library is higher level (many functions are built-in, such as registration, segmentation, recognition algorithms) and is based on OpenNI for low-level operations. Personnally, I would recommend you give a try to the Point Cloud Library, linked in my answer, and look for an alternative if you enconter a really specific need not covered by PCL.